# How to find Source, which is providing data for binding in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, mvvm

- I am beginner in `WPF`. In terms of debugging big project built using `MVVM` pattern, how we can find the **source**, which is providing data to current binding element?
- For example,

```xml
 <DataTemplate x:Key="TMPL_NameColumnB">
                <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
                          Panel.ZIndex="1"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding TypeChoices}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding TypeChoice}"
                          Visibility="{Binding DataContext.CanChangeType,
                          Converter={StaticResource {x:Type BooleanToVisibilityConverter}},
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
```

- For above Data template how can I find out, which Objects `TypeChoices`, property is used for binding.
- This question is to find out how to find Source of data binding while debugging.

Comment: MainWinodw.DataContext object is what you need to look for, The typeof(DataContext) is the actual object witch is providing the data for bidnings.

Comment: I'm not currently developing with WPF, there might be better tooling now, but "back in the days" I used [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) when I wanted to inspect a WPF application at runtime regarding hard-to-debug aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to inspect the `DataContext` of the element of interest.
   For example, if you want to check the source of the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` data binding:
   **a)** first review the binding expression. In this case, it will use the implicit source notation `{Binding PropertyPath}` that always points to the local/inherited `DataContext` as source (but it could as well set the properties `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` or the `Source` property explicitly, which would change the source along the visual tree). The local `DataContext` is the `DataContext` of the element the binding is defined on: `ComboBox.DataContext`.
   **b)** use a visual tree inspector to find the `ComboBox` and inspect the `DataContext` property.

   If the binding had defined the `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` property you would lookup the corresponding element and inspect its `DataContext` instead.

   [Inspect XAML properties while debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2022)
   [How to: Use the WPF Tree Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-wpf-tree-visualizer?view=vs-2022)
   [Introducing the UI debugging tools for XAML](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-the-ui-debugging-tools-for-xaml/)
2. Alternatively, enabled the debugger tracer to output binding information. If the trace level for data binding is set to e.g. `Information` or `Verbose` you should find the data source of the particular binding by inspecting the trace output in the Output window.

   [How to: Display WPF Trace Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-display-wpf-trace-information?view=vs-2022)

   To change the trace level for a particular binding you can set the [`PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) attached property.
   Simply attach it to the `Binding` object:

```xml
<!-- Note: you would have to define a `xmlns` import 
     and qualify the attached property using the alias. -->
<ComboBox xmlns:systemDiag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items, systemDiag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
```

3. If the binding of interest produces an error, you can always open the Visual Studio "XAML Binding Failures" tool window and inspect the binding from there.
   See [XAML data binding diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-data-binding-diagnostics?view=vs-2022)

Comment: you are awesome, I wish I could give you hug now. By the way, is there any source or something you recommend to enhance and powerful my skills in ```MVVM``` pattern?

Comment: There is really nothing special about MVVM. It's just a pattern that partitions your application into three components.  MVVM requires the implementaion of two simple rules: **1**) Application is structured into three components (M-V-VM) **2)** Those components are part of an unidirectional dependency graph: *View ---> View Model ---> Model*.

Comment: All you have to do is **a)** to ensure not to violate component responsibilities: be carefully when deciding in which component you define your classes. Then be careful to not mix responsibilities i.e. prevent e.g. the View from bleeding into the View Model (for example the View Model participates in UI logic). In other words, do not violate rule #1. **b)** to be careful to respect the dependency graph direction when dependencies cross application boundaries (for example do not reference View modules from the View Model component). In other words, do not violate rule #2.

Comment: That's all. No skills required at this point. The skills come into play when designing your classes and application layers and implementing the details. For example, at least know your design patterns, the SOLID principles and clean code.

Answer (score 2):

- Check the `Enable in-app toolbar` option under Tools->Options->XAML Hot Reload in Visual Studio
- Start the application using the Debug->Start Debugging option
- Click on the `Go to Live Visual Tree` button on the in-app toolbar when running the application
- Click on the `Select Element` button to select the element to which the template is applied
- In Visual Studio, while the app is still running, right-click on the selected element in the visual tree and select `Show Properties`
- Look at the value for the `DataContext` property in the `Live Property Explorer`. It reveals the current `DataContext` of the element. This type should have a public property named `TypeChoices` for your binding to work.

Please refer to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for more information about how to inspect XAML properties while debugging.

Comment: you are awesome, I wish I could give you hug now. By the way, is there any source or something you recommend to enhance and powerful my skills in ```MVVM``` pattern?

Comment: I wish I could mark your answer as accepted, please consider it as ```accepted```.